# from .models import User SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Tags: python, django, excel

I got an error,`from .models import User SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import'.
I wanna parse excel and put data in the model(User).User model in models.py is

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    man = models.BooleanField()
```

The last code of man = models.BooleanField() means man or woman, if ’●’ in excel, it means the user is a man and true wanna be put in man variable. Now views.py is

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd
from .models import User

  book = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/data.xlsx')
  sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

  for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
        rows = sheet.row(row_index)  
        print(rows) 
  for row in rows:
        is_man = row[4] != ""
        user = User(user_id=row[1], name_id=row[2], age=row[3], man=is_man)
        user.save()
```

I removed the import and used my IDE to import it, but now error happens `from app.models import User ImportError: No module named 'app''.However, models.py & views.py are in app(it is child app) folder, so I really cannot understand why No module named 'app' error happens.
How can I fix this? 
setting.py was changed

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
]
```

only adding 'app', and URLs.py in child app (it is named app. test is parent app name )is empty.

Comment: i try to fix your code but it has some errors, please fix it, and format you errors messages

Comment: @BearBrown I fix my question.Is it ok?

Comment: did your try to run it yourself? variable `rows` not declared

Comment: add settings.py and urls.py of project

Comment: @BearBrown Oh,my old &new code is mixed.sorry

Comment: @AstikAnand I added my info.